# Canonical software comparisons acceptable?

Tags: discussion, scope

I started [this thread](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/32508/perl-gui-toolkits), aiming to be a canonical source for documenting differences between Perl GUI toolkits.

I have added a few toolkits, but a moderator, [Undo](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/46/undo), put it on hold as too broad, recommending I ask here for others' thoughts about it.

Is this question on-topic? I certainly believe it would be useful, as one could then reference all other Perl GUI toolkit questions there, but what do others think?

Comment: FYI [Software Comparisons](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/93761/software-comparisons)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simply too broad (and Undo was simply faster than me in closing it). As you can see in our help center, SR recommends software for ***specific*** requirements – while your question was just for *any* Toolkit. Result of that would be a list of names, which is frowned upon at almost all SE sites.